# Terraform 11 Additional Security Group Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, continuous-integration, terraform, amazon-efs

I'm adding additional security groups in Terraform 11, using AWS Provider 2.70.0 to an EFS Mount Target.

The code block is:

```
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "default" {
  count          = "${length(split(",",var.backend_subnets)) > 0 ? length(split(",",var.backend_subnets)) : 0}"
  file_system_id = "${aws_efs_file_system.default.id}"
  ip_address     = "${var.mount_target_ip_address}"
  subnet_id      = "${element(split(",", var.backend_subnets), count.index)}"
  security_groups = ["${var.additional_security_groups == "" ? aws_security_group.efs_default_sg.id : format("%s,%s",var.additional_security_groups,aws_security_group.efs_default_sg.id)}"]
}
```

The variable definition is:

```
variable "additional_security_groups" {
  description = "Comma separated string of security group ID's"
  default     = ""
}
```

But the following errors are occurring:

```
* module.efs.aws_efs_mount_target.default[1]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_efs_mount_target.default.1: ValidationException:
status code: 400, request id: 5ee48121-27c3-432b-98e9-e2ffdc6e0fdd

plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.70.0_x4: 2021/03/26 17:49:50 [ERR] plugin: plugin server: accept unix /tmp/plugin935042092: use of closed network connection
```

There is no issue when run without the additional security group.

Comment: Try `TF_LOG=debug` so you can see the actual request sent to AWS and the response.

Comment: That error is from TF_LOG=debug. I think this is an AWS Provider Plugin issue.

Comment: @TheoSweeny the security groups you are providing are those belongs to the same VPC as the specified subnet? and the security groups are in the form of `sg-xxx`? Why it works without security group is `If the request provides SecurityGroups, this network interface is associated with those security groups. Otherwise, it belongs to the default security group for the subnet's VPC.`  [CreateMountTarget](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/API_CreateMountTarget.html#API_CreateMountTarget_RequestParameters). Why I am considering this because the error i `ValidationException` .

Comment: Yes both SG's are in the same VPC.

Comment: how's the `aws_efs_file_system ` resource looks like?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was not with the plugin but was with the compare statement for the security groups.

The working compare:

```
security_groups = ["${split(",", length(var.additional_security_groups) > 0 ? join(",", concat(list(aws_security_group.efs_default_sg.id), var.additional_security_groups)) : join(",", list(aws_security_group.efs_default_sg.id)))}"]
```

And to support this, the variable type had to be changed to list:

```
variable "additional_security_groups" {
  description = "Comma separated list of security group ID's"
  default     = ["sg-123","sg-789"]
}
```